# Grails 2.3 compiling issue

Tags: java, grails, compiler-errors, grails-2.3

I have a Grails 2.3.0 project that uses CXF plugin. With CXF "`wsdl2java`" I have generated some java files which I have compiled into a JAR file. The JAR file I have put in the "lib" folder of my project. I use some of the types from the JAR in my code - so far so good!

Running `grails compile` works fine! **BUT!** Running `grails compile` again fails. It complains about missing classes from the JAR file. Running `grails clean` solves the issue, and the code compiles nicely again (and works as intended btw!).

The setup worked fine with Grails 2.2.4. Any ideas on how to solve this issue are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The following helped me to resolve the problem:

1. Use Aether instead of Ivy. Add to BuildConfig.groovy:

   grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
2. Check that you grails plugins are inside 'plugins' section not 'dependencies' in BuildConfig.groovy
3. Disable fork execution in BuildConfig.groovy:

   grails.project.fork = [
           test: false,
           run: false,
           war: false,
           console: false
   ]